# uploading images in public dir reactjs/nextjs

Tags: path, next.js, multer

I've been trying to upload images in the `/public` directory this code is working fine locally (Windows OS)

```
import getConfig from "next/config";
import fs from "fs";
const address=path.join(getConfig().serverRuntimeConfig.PROJECT_ROOT, `/public/uploads/users/${username}`);
if (!fs.existsSync(address)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(address, { recursive: true });
}
```

I'm using multer for file uploading from client-side.

The above code is working fine on window os locally but in after deployment at vercel it throws the error:

> 2022-03-21T16:05:16.872Z  693e7f44-12d9-4f4e-90cf-f030a299f918    ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection
> {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"Error:
> ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir
> '/vercel/path0/public/uploads/users/saif'","reason":{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"ENOENT:
> no such file or directory, mkdir
> '/vercel/path0/public/uploads/users/saif'","code":"ENOENT","errno":-2,"syscall":"mkdir","path":"/vercel/path0/public/uploads/users/saif","stack":["Error:
> ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir
> '/vercel/path0/public/uploads/users/saif'","    at Object.mkdirSync
> (fs.js:1013:3)","    at DiskStorage.destination [as getDestination]
> (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/User/index.js:155:55)","    at
> processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)","
> at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:64:3)","    at
> processImmediate
> (internal/timers.js:437:9)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection:
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir
> '/vercel/path0/public/uploads/users/saif'","    at process.
> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)","    at process.emit
> (events.js:412:35)","    at processPromiseRejections
> (internal/process/promises.js:245:33)","    at
> processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:96:32)","
> at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:64:3)","    at
> processImmediate (internal/timers.js:437:9)"]} Unknown application
> error occurred

Answer (score 1):

Vercel as a platform does not allow persistent file storage as these are serverless functions, they encourage uploads to a bucket like s3 -

https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/solutions/file-storage

- Create a Serverless Function to return a presigned URL.
- From the front-end, call your Serverless Function to get the presigned POST  URL.
- Allow the user to upload a file on the front-end. Forward the
- file to the POST URL.

Note: here the presigned url is a s3 location that you are creating as a location.

They also post multiple examples by using different examples using s3 or Google storage bucket.